# Eclipse - redirect all logger output to console

Tags: java, eclipse, logging, console

I'm using Eclipse to run applications using maven tomcat plugin in local environment.

Each class uses `org.apache.log4j.Logger` to log, as:

```
private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(MyClass.class);
```

Can I redirect all log output to Eclipse's Console log?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add a console appender to your log4j.xml like:

```
<log4j:configuration>
    <appender name="console" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
        <param name="target" value="System.out"/>
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="conversionPattern" value="%d [%t] %-5p %c - %m%n"/>
        </layout>
    </appender>
    <root>
        <level value="DEBUG" />
        <appender-ref ref="console" />
    </root>
   ...
</log4j:configuration>
```

See also: https://www.mkyong.com/logging/log4j-xml-example/

A vaild logger looks like:

```
 <logger name="com.package.Class">
    <level value="info" />
 </logger>
```

Comment: Do you also log to a file and does it contain the logs?

Comment: than it would be useful if you add your current config to the question

Comment: Then try the example from the linked page, I assumed you already had a working config and only need to add another appender.

Answer (score 1):

You can configure log4j to print to console/file through the link provided by @stacker

https://www.mkyong.com/logging/log4j-xml-example/

**but to add it in pom.xml add the file path inside `<systemProperties>` tag**

```
<plugin>
<groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
<artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<configuration>
    <port>8080</port>
    <path>/</path>
    <systemProperties>
     <log4j.configuration>file:src/main/resources/log4j.properties</log4j.configuration>
    </systemProperties>
</configuration>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.17</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: My `log4j.xml` is found in classes folder, should I use `file:classes/log4j.xml`?

Comment: I succeeded loaded file (as `file:c:\eclipse\Product\target\classes\log4j.xml`) But still no log is added to eclipse's conole

Comment: @user7294900 with maven you are supposed to place the config files in src/main/resources during compilation they will be copied to target/classes

Comment: @user7294900 put your config files in resources folder as stated by stacker